# Lots of directories created by storm on runtime

Tags: apache-storm

I am working on local Mode cluster of Storm(0.9.1) on centos. When I submit the topology, storm will created lots of directories(named like `1aedef5c-d785-4b45-b8b5-26930f1ab338`) in tmp directory. Someone said that it will delete all the created directories from tmp, when we kill the topology. But in my case I will never kill the topology. My tmp directory size is increasing.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: May I ask why apache-kafka is tagged here? Are you using Kafka as part of this setup?

Comment: Yes I am using Kafka spout.

Answer (score 0):

The following comments received from nathanmarz

> Local mode isn't meant to be run for long periods of time. It chooses
>   a unique temp path for the in process Zookeeper's data, but since it's
>   not running compaction that Zookeeper instance will eventually use up
>   the disk space

You can find the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/Q7-sM42gWi0)

Comment: but why is making lots of directories. Can we make it in a single directory.